# PHP search feature, where comparing an encrypted value

Tags: php, search, encryption, cryptography, sql-like

I am making a search feature where the search value should be compared with two columns in a db table. One column is just a name and the other column is en encrypted value in format "xxxxxx-xxxx" (only numbers). The user should be able to just search for part of the total string in the table.

For the name comparison I use `where name LIKE %search_value%`, but for the encrypted value I can't use that way of doing it.

Any ideas to how a good way of doing the comparison would be?

Comment: What is the "encrypted value"?

Comment: Could you provide some examples, i.e. what might the user search for and which rows should be returned when?

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't use a wildcard search for crypted values, because the crypting of 'a' is ENTIRELY and UTTERLY different than the crypting of 'bac'. There's no practical method of doing sub-string matching within a crypted field. However, a simple direct equality test is doable. If you're a DB-side function like mysql's aes_encrypt(), then you could do

```
... WHERE
      (name LIKE '%search%') OR
      (cryptedfield = AES_ENCRYPT('search', 'key'))
```

For substring matching, you'd have to decrypt the field first:

```
... WHERE
    (name LIKE '%search%') OR
    (AES_DECRYPT(cryptedfield, 'key') LIKE '%search%')
```

Comment: Just a head's up: AES_ENCRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT() do not produce semantically secure encryption and therefore shouldn't be used. Specifically, they implement [ECB](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin).

Answer (score 0):

basically, if it needs to be encrypted, no part of the system should be able to search it. if it should be searchable, then it probably doesn't need to be encrypted.

otherwise you are kind of defeating the purpose of encryption.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for full-text search capability of encrypted data (without the database server being able to decrypt the messages), you're in academic research territory.

*However*, if you only need a limited subset of searching capabilities on encrypted data, you can use [blind indexes](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql) constructed from the plaintext which can be used in SELECT queries.

So instead of:

```
SELECT *
FROM humans
WHERE name LIKE '%search_value%';
```

You could do this:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM humans h 
JOIN humans_blind_indexes hb ON hb.human_id = h.id
WHERE hb.first_initial_last_name = $1 OR hb.first_name = $2 OR hb.last_name = $3
```

And then pass it three truncated hash function outputs, and you'll get your database records with matching ciphertexts.

This isn't just a theoretical remark, you can actually do this today with [this open source library](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet/).